# detect touch on GUI Textures

Tags: user-interface, mouse, unity-game-engine

I have 2 gui textures.

According to screen width and height i kept it in gui.

One for joystick and another for shooter.

Now touching on shooter joystick moves to that specific portion.

i used rect.Contains.

```
void Start () {
xx = Screen.width - Screen.width/12;
yy = Screen.height - Screen.height/8; 
lb = Screen.width/10;
rect = new Rect(-xx/2, -yy/2, lb, lb);
shooter.pixelInset  = rect;       
shooter.enabled = false;      
}

void OnGUI(){
if(characterScript.playbool){
   shooter.enabled = true;
} 
if (rect.Contains(Event.current.mousePosition)){
shootBool = true;
print("shoot");
alert.text="shoot";
}   
}
```

Not working properly for me. Think space coordinates are different from gui coordinates. How can fix this problem.do anyone can suggest any other good method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`HitTest`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUIElement.HitTest.html).

```
function Update()
{
    for (var touch : Touch in Input.touches)
    {
        if (rect.Contains(touch.position))
        {
            // we are now in the guitexture 'rect'
            Debug.Log("rect touched");
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is used with touches, as you described in your question. However, since you tagged `mouse`, I don't know for sure if you use the mouse or a touch.

So, if you use the mouse to click on the object, you can use:

```
if (rect.Contains(Input.mousePosition) && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    Debug.Log("rect clicked");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Getting error error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Rect' does not contain a definition for `HitTest' and no extension method `HitTest' of type `UnityEngine.Rect' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Oh excuse me, that only works on GUI Elements. You can try `rect.Contains(touch.position)` instead!

Comment: i have 2 buttons. One for shooter and another for joystick. So for both how can i do it.

Comment: Place the above Update-code in a class and attach it to your button. Use the code on top for touch, and below for mouse clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Some debugging of your code brings out a few problems.

Say the screen resolution is 800x600px:

```
xx = 800 - 800 / 12
   = 733.3333333333333
yy = 600 - 600 / 8
   = 525
lb = 800 / 10
   = 80
rect = (-366.665, -262.5, 80, 80)
```

Why is `lb` determined by the screen width divided by ten?

Now the heart of the problem is that `Event.mousePosition` starts at the top left of the screen, while `GUITexture.pixelInset` is based in the center of the screen.

You will have to either adjust the `Event.mousePosition` to use the center of the screen as the origin, or you will have to adjust the `rect` variable to start at the top-left of the screen.